# android spin button text 90 degrees

Tags: android, xml, button

i have a screen filled with buttons in my app and i need to have three specific buttons to turn 90 degree so their text will be turned i tried to use

```
android:rotation="90"
```

it fixed my text direction problem but it made it so the button be too small (the button kept their width size)
i need it will look like this
[image]

for this three button i need to change (the button that said 1st12 2st12 and 3st12) is:

```
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="1st12"
            android:rotation="90"
             />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="2st12"
            android:rotation="90"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="3st12"
            android:rotation="90"/>
```

any help will be great thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can custom TextView:

```
public class VerticalTextView extends TextView{
   final boolean topDown;

   public VerticalTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
      super(context, attrs);
      final int gravity = getGravity();
      if(Gravity.isVertical(gravity) && (gravity&Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK) == Gravity.BOTTOM) {
         setGravity((gravity&Gravity.HORIZONTAL_GRAVITY_MASK) | Gravity.TOP);
         topDown = false;
      }else
         topDown = true;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
      super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
      setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredHeight(), getMeasuredWidth());
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean setFrame(int l, int t, int r, int b){
      return super.setFrame(l, t, l+(b-t), t+(r-l));
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas){
      if(topDown){
         canvas.translate(getHeight(), 0);
         canvas.rotate(90);
      }else {
         canvas.translate(0, getWidth());
         canvas.rotate(-90);
      }
      canvas.clipRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), android.graphics.Region.Op.REPLACE);
      super.draw(canvas);
   }
}
```